# It's possible to assign an certificate to an public ip address?

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate

In these days we received the notification that our public ip's have issues with the certificate assigned to it.
My questions are :
Can you assign a certificate SSL/TLS to an public ip?
Is the service provider the one who can implement the certificate ?

THANKS IN ADVANCE FOR HELP!
Let me know if you need more detail about configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you is talking about SSL certificate.

> Can you assign a certificate SSL/TLS to an public IP?

## Absolutely No.

I am not a public CA and also not a trusted CA.

If I issue you a certificate, the certificate is **not** public and it is **not** trusted.

> Is the service provider the one who can implement the certificate ?

I assume the 'service provider' is a CA (Certificate Authority).

There are a lot of public CA that is trusted on every major devices and they are selling* certificate.

If you buy a certificate, the CA will immediatelly** issue you a certificate.

*You can only buy certificate for public IP address. No CA will issue a public IP certificate unless they get paid.

**Based on your selected certificate option. There are two option for public IP, DV or OV.

DV certificate will be issue immediately after you verifies your public IP address.

OV will verify your public IP address and your organation/company.

If you are individual, you can choose DV.